# Java setPreferredSize() by referance

Tags: java, reference, preferredsize

I am attempting to create an animatable JPanel and coming from C I have created an Animator object which increments a Double object to help with this.

I would like to pass in a reference to the preferredSize width of a JPanel and have it modify this width directly. Is this possible? I understand Java doesn't have references to primitive types and even if it did, simply changing its value may not update the view appropriately.

```
private class Animator {
    private Double value;
    private Double increment;
    private Double target;

    public Animator(Double value, Double increment, Double target) {
        this.value = value;
        this.increment = increment;
        this.target = target;
    }

    public boolean step() {
        value += increment;
        if (value >= target) {
            value = target;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly, but if passing the JPanel to the method is an option, you could do it that way.  For ex:

```
public static void updateSize(JPanel panel)
{
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was hoping to have a generic way of animating values so that instead of explicitly updating the size, position etc. I can just create Animators for those fields and update them all simultaneously.